# Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} \frac{x+6}{x^{4}-4x^{3}+x^{2}+x+6}=-1$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} \frac{x+6}{x^{4}-4x^{3}+x^{2}+x+6}=-1$

You should start by writing $\frac{x+6}{x^{4}-4x^{3}+x^{2}+x+6} + 1$ in the way $\left ( x-3 \right )g\left ( x \right )$

(a) Determine $g(x)$

(b) Could we choose $\delta = \min\lbrace 1, \frac{\varepsilon }{n} \rbrace$ for some $n$? Why?

(c) If we choose $\delta = \min\lbrace \frac{1}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon }{m} \rbrace$ , what is the smallest integer $m$ that we could use?

---

I managed to answer the part (a): By making the sum of the fraction with +1, and factoring the numerator, I get the following:

$\frac{\left ( x-3 \right )\left ( x^{3} - x^{2} - 2x - 4 \right )}{x^{4} - 4x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 6}$

where

$g\left ( x \right ) = \frac{\left ( x^{3} - x^{2} - 2x - 4 \right )}{x^{4} - 4x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 6}$

But my problem is when developing the part (b).

In the part (b) I am using the formal limit definition, but I am not managing to reach a result that allows me to find the answer.

I need help to solve this exercise, please

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "I managed to answer the part (a)"  Then why the @#%\$& aren't you including the answer in your post?

Comment: Note:  If $w < 1$ then $w > w^2 > w^3 > ..........$.  SO often the $\delta = \min(1, whatevah)$ serve the purpose to assure all $w^k$ for larger values $k$ are negligible.

Comment: I do not understand your reasoning. I was watching exercises where they apply the formal limit definition, and by obtaining an epsilon value depending on x, many of the exercises came to develop $\left | x - c \right | < \delta $ in order to obtain a constant value of Epsilon, and therefore, Delta.

But in this exercise, f (x) is a fraction with Fourth Power Polinomials, which is making me complicated to apply the formal definition of limit.

Comment: @fleablood Also when users said they tried everything, but don't put even a single attempt in their answer

Comment: Okay so if $|x-3| < \delta < 1$ then $2< x < 4$. and $x^3-x^2-2x -4>x^3>8$ and $x^4 -4x^3+x^2+x+6< 4*x^3 - 4x^3 + x^2 + x + 6 < 26$ so $g(x)> \frac 8{26}$ and $x^3-x^2-2x -4< 4*x^2 -x^2 -2x-4=3x^2 -2x -4< 3x^2-12< 48-12=36$. And $x^4-4x^3 +x^2 +x+6>x^4+x^2 + x + 6> 16+4+2+6=28$ so $g(x) < \frac {36}{28}$ so $\frac 4{13} < g(x) < \frac 97$.  So $|x-3|\cdot \frac 4{13} < |(x-3)g(x)| < |x-3|\cdot \frac 97$.  So if $\delta = \min(1, \frac 79\epsilon)$ ......

Comment: Insisting on smallest value of $m$ is simply pointless in part c). Perhaps the question setter themselves are not clear about definition of limit. We don't need any special $\delta$ but just some $\delta$ which works according to definition.

Comment: You should note that denominator of $g(x) $ does not vanish at $x=3$ and hence there should be some interval containing $3$ where this denominator is non-zero. And further it has different signs at $3,4$ so that $\delta<1$ is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated question. You need to find a suitable bound for the rational function $g(x) $ for values of $x$ in a certain neighborhood of $3$. In formal terms we need two positive numbers $h, K$ such that $|g(x) |<K$ whenever $|x-3|<h$.

This clearly requires an analysis of numerator and denominator of $g$. Note that the function can not be bounded if the denominator of $g$ vanishes. Since it does not vanish at $3$ we have a guarantee by continuity of polynomials that the denominator will not vanish in some neighborhood of $3$.

Finding such a neighborhood (ie finding $h$ described above) is possible using the limit of denominator $q(x) =x^4-4x^3+x^2+x+6$ as $x\to 3$. But before we do that let's observe that $q(3)<0,q(4)>0$ and hence $q$ vanishes somewhere between $3,4$ and thus $h$ must be less than $1$.

Thus for part b) the answer is no. You can't expect a $\delta$ like $\min(1,\dots)$ to work. You should observe that $h$ described above forms the first argument of $\min$ in expression for $\delta$.

Part c) is about showing that we can take $h=1/4$. Let us now prove that $q(x)\to - 9$ as $x\to 3$. Clearly $$|q(x) +9|=|x-3||x^3-x^2-2x+5|$$ and $$|x^3-x^2-2x+5|=|x(x-2)(x+1)+5|$$ If $|x-3|<1/2$ then $5/2<x<7/2$ and hence $$|x(x-2)(x+1)+5|<(7/2)(3/2)(9/2)+5<32$$ and thus for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $$|q(x) +9|<\epsilon$$ if $|x-3|<\min(1/2,\epsilon /32)$. Using $\epsilon =8$ we can see that $$|q(x) +9|<8$$ if $|x-3|<1/4$. Thus $|q(x) |>1$ if $|x-3|<1/4$.

Next we deal with numerator $p(x) =x^3-x^2-2x-4$ of $g(x) $. Clearly if $|x-3|<1/4$ then $2.5<x<3.5$ and $$|p(x) |=|x(x-2)(x+1)-4|<28$$ Thus it follows that if $|x-3|<1/4$ then $$|g(x) |=|p(x) |/|q(x) |<28$$
It should now be clear that $$|(x-3)g(x)|<28|x-3|$$ and this is less than $\epsilon$ if $|x-3|<\min(1/4,\epsilon/28)$. This proves the desired limit in question.

It does not however make sense to find the smallest positive integer which can replace $28$ above. Finding such numbers becomes an algebraic problem related to solution of inequalities and is really not in the spirit of epsilon-delta definition of limit.

Comment: I don't think the downvote is related to activities in CURED. If there is any specific issue with the answer I can try to fix or elaborate further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Paramanand Singh. I managed to understand very well the development of your reasoning to resolve exercise. I am grateful for your help.

Comment: @hellkaiser: glad to help. But someone perhaps didn't like my answer and gave a downvote. If you find the answer useful you may upvote it and accept it.

Comment: +1. I specially liked the part where $h$ was concluded to be $<1$ though I didn't understand part $(c)$. In particular, does it really matter what is smallest positive $m$ as whatever it is, $\epsilon \gt 0$ being arbitrary can take care of that? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Koro: in the end of my answer I have also mentioned that we don't need to find smallest $m$. I still wonder why the question setter asked that. So your understanding is correct.

Comment: @Koro: however with some more effort (but it is a pointless thing here to do) we can find desired minimum $m$. To do that we need to find the maximum value, say $M$, of $|g(x) |$ on $[2.75,3.25]$ and take $m$ as the least positive integer which is greater than or equal to $M$ ie $m=\lceil M\rceil$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Thanks a lot 